# c# linq update all records in database

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, records

im trying to update all records in a sql table using the following code but no data is updated. does anyone know why?

```
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            foreach (Item record in db.Items)
            {
                record.Description += "bla";
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

code for setter:

```
[Column(Storage="_Description", DbType="NVarChar(400) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)] 
public string Description
{ 
  get { return this._Description; }
  set { 
      if ((this._Description != value))
       { 
         this._Description = value; 
       }
      }
}
```

Comment: You might want to change the tags to LINQ2SQL - this is a LINQ2SQL question, not just linq.

Comment: Do you get any messages while attempting the update?

Comment: no messages, everything looked like it was working.

Comment: After the loop, what is returned if you call db.GetChangeSet()?

Comment: (with the SubmitChanges() call outside the loop as suggested below, before this is called, and check the Updates list of the returned ChangeSet)

Comment: it says 0 updates, 0 inserts, 0 deletes.....

Comment: Can you post the contents of the setter for the Description property of Item

Comment: [Column(Storage="_Description", DbType="NVarChar(400) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
  public string Description
  {
   get
   {
    return this._Description;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._Description != value))
    {
     this._Description = value;
    }
   }
  }

Comment: @Grant I have added the code for the setter to the post hope you don't mind.

Comment: I have provided an answer below, this should hopefully solve your problem...

Answer (score 4):

Out of curiosity, see if moving the SubmitChanges() outside of the loop makes a difference:

```
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            foreach (Item record in db.Items)
            {
                record.Description += "bla";   
            }
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Nope, It wouldn't work out that way. It maybe improve efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

From the details of the setter you have posted in the comments, your Description property has not been correctly created for notification of property changes. Did you write the property yourself or was it generated by the VS2008 tooling?

Your Item class (all Linq to Sql entities for that matter should implement INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged) which will give you both PropertyChanging event and PropertyChanged events, if you used the VS2008 tools you should get a couple of methods like the following in your entity classes:

```
    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Now within your setter of your property you should use these methods to raise the required events:

```
[Column(Name="Description", Storage="_Description",
                  DbType="NVarChar(400) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]   
public string Description
{
     get { return this._Description; }
     set
     {
         if ((this._Description != value))
         {
             this.SendPropertyChanging("Description");
             this._Description = value;
             this.SendPropertyChanged("Description");
         }
     }
 }
```

I also noticed you don't have the Name property set in your column attribute so add it just in case (I have it included in my example assuming your column name is "Description").

Comment: Because of the implemented code I couldn't see any error which can prevent from updating but the error must be in setter.

Comment: Hi Simon, the DBML data was created completely from within VS2008. After following your instructions i still cannot get any data to update and the changeset returns 0...

Comment: Maybe there is something ridiculously basic i have overlooked like no primary key or something really really simple...

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the SendPropertyChanging and SendPropertyChanged methods to check that the DataContext is registered for those notifications (i.e. the event properties are not null)?

Comment: Aaah, yes if you have no Primary Key on your table that will explain why the INotifyChanging and INotifyChanged interfaces are not being emitted by the generator. This would have actually choked on anything other than Update i.e. Insert or Delete (I'm pretty sure :) so you would have noticed. You can get around this (if you can't modify the table) by setting the PrimaryKey property to true on one of the tables columns in the Linq designer. However this will still cause issues if there ends up being duplicate data in the table.

Comment: I might take a fresh look at this later on.. thankyou all for you suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to supply a connection string.

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(_MyConnectionString))
{
    foreach (Item record in db.Items)
    {
        record.Description += "bla";
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I've had some strange issues with the DataContext when not supplying a connection string.

Answer (score 2):

I will point out you can SubmitChanges after the loop closes... This won't solve your problem but it will help out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a really old question, but it remains unanswered.

The answer provided by Simon Fox is technically correct, and the suggestion by BFree is a big time saver.

Yet, if your table does not have a Primary Key specified in the table, the DBML object will not detect a change and does not know how to update your records.

[image: screenshot]